# regex works differently in R when function is from a different script

Tags: r, regex

I have two R scripts:

**test1.R**

```
fun1 <- function(x){
  gsub("²","2", x)
}
```

**test2.R**

```
source("test1.R")

fun2 <- function(x){
  gsub("²","2", x)
}

x <- "A²"

fun1(x)
fun2(x)
```

I would expect the results of `fun1` and `fun2` to be the same. But if I run the code in `test2.R` I get.

```
> fun1(x)
[1] "A²"

> fun2(x)
[1] "A2"
```

Why are the results different and how can I get `fun1` to give the same result as `fun2`? I am using RStudio 1.2.5019 and my System Info is:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1 tools_3.6.1
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two functions and why is `source` relevant?

Comment: The functions are the same, that is the point

Comment: I unfortunately cannot reproduce.Maybe someone else can.

Comment: I get the exact same output (`A2`) for `fun2` and the function sourced from the `test1.R` script.

Comment: What version of R are you using? What OS?

Comment: R version `3.5.3`, platform `x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0`, OS `darwin15.6.0`.

Comment: Perhaps it is a windows problem?

Comment: Windows here, latest R release.

Comment: Have you checked the encoding of your scripts, e.g. UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, ...?

Comment: How do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure both files have the same encoding (preferably `UTF-8`). Use `Save with encoding ...` from RStudio. If the problem still there, try to copy the `"²"` to an `R` console to check if they are really the same (`"²" == "²"`).

Update:

As the problem still persist, you can try:

1. `source("test1.R", encoding="UTF-8")`
2. `eval(parse("test1.R", encoding="UTF-8"))`

Comment: I got "²" == "²"  TRUE

Comment: Encoding is UTF-8 for both files